# What does "turn right" and "turn left" mean in fixed memory method of flood filling an area?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to flood fill a region, that specific algorithm is given in the following [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) document under the heading of "Fixed memory method(right-hand fill method)" . The specific part of the algorithm where the left and right turns take place is given below...

```
START:
    set count to number of non-diagonally adjacent pixels filled (front/back/left/right ONLY)
    if count is not 4
            do
                    turn right
            while front-pixel is empty
            do
                    turn left
            while front-pixel is filled
    end if
```

The statement explicitly states to turn right or turn left and not move right or move left. What is confusing for me is, how can a pixel at (x,y) coordinate be turned to its right of its left?

Comment: Thanks Joonas Pulakka and brimborium for your quick helpful replies. The statements "move forward" and "turn left/right" put me slightly off track. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: Glad we could help. You can also [accept one of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Just choose the answer that helped you or others with the same problem the most.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that forward initially means "up". Turning right changes the meaning of forward - now it would mean "right". Turn right again, and forward is "down".

Answer (score 1):

You basically can think of your "pixel" as a bug/ant/dinosaur/golden unicorn. So there is not only a location, but also a direction, it is facing (the **orientation**). So if your pixel *looks up*, then the command `turn right` will tell it to look to the right side. `move forward` would then mean to move one pixel to the right.

If you tell your pixel to `turn right` 4 times, it will look in the same direction as before. 3x`turn right` is the same as 1x`turn left`.